# Dropdown menu links are not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a responsive nav bar from the tutorial on W3 School using HTML and JavaScript. The dropdown menu links on my responsive navigation bar are working fine on the desktop, but on my iphone, nothing happens when I click on the menu links.

```
Here is the link to my CodePen:
```

http://codepen.io/dsemel/full/WrYBye/

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In general that pattern along with expanding buttons is troublesome on iOS, to the point of needing completely different design of html. can it be same workarounds as for iPad?

Comment: I don't own an iPad, but I will research that solution. Do Android mobile phones also have this problem?

Comment: Please, check CSS media queries for IOS! Btw, functionality on Android works well!

Comment: @DanielSemel did you figure out why?

Comment: @Mohamad Yes, Codepen does blocks anchor links from working. You would have to use target_blank for a link to open in Codepen.